# PyAutoGui Confirm window change location

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I would like to change the location of the PyAutoGui confirm window that pops up. How can I do this?

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.confirm(text='title', title='title', buttons=['1', '2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the way to choose the location of the confirm box, is not stated. But a temporary solution, would be to use a set of drag and drop actions knowing the default location of the confirm box, to move the boxes to whatever pixel coordinates needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem I am having with that solution is that until I close the confirm window, I can't run any commands or lines of code.

Comment: you can make a new post, with the following problem, if you still have it/